# PowerShell - ParentContainsErrorRecordException when specifying default string parameter

Tags: powershell, parameters, default-value

I am trying to write a powershell script which needs a few different parameters to be specified when executing it (some mandatory, some not). Some of those parameters have a default value that should be used when the user did not specify any other value instead of the default value.
For some reason I just can't figure out how to do this. My current code looks like this:

```
param
(
    [Parameter(Position=0,Mandatory)]
    [string[]]$TemplateNames,
    [Parameter(Position=1)]
    [string]$Mode = "d",
    [Parameter(Position=2)]
    [string]$Log = $env:TEMP
)
```

With this code I always get the error "ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException" in the line where I define the Mode parameter and an exception message telling me that the expression is invalid because the assignment operator must be an object which can accept assignments. What am I doing wrong? This should be fairly simple and easy to do but I just don't understand how I am supposed to do this.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see anything wrong with this param block. Just to be sure, I tested this in powershell core 7 and it worked fine.

```bsh
param
(
    [Parameter(Position=0,Mandatory)]
    [string[]]$TemplateNames,

    [Parameter(Position=1)]
    [string]$Mode = "d",
    
    [Parameter(Position=2)]
    [string]$Log = $env:TEMP
)

"TemplateNames: {0}" -f ($TemplateNames -join ",")

"Mode: {0}" -f $Mode

"Log {0}" -f $Log
```

```
# only pass templates
.\foo.ps1 a,b,c
TemplateNames: a,b,c
Mode: d
Log C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp

# pass templates and mode
.\foo.ps1 a,b,c X
TemplateNames: a,b,c
Mode: X
Log C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp

# pass templates, mode and log path
.\foo.ps1 a,b,c X c:\temp\foobar
TemplateNames: a,b,c
Mode: X
Log c:\temp\foobar
```

Remember that if you wanted to pass log and templates, but NOT mode, you'd have to use named parameters (because of the strict ordering of positions)

```
.\foo.ps1 a,b,c -Log c:\temp\foobar
```

Comment: Thanks for the response! I just figured out what's the problem. I had a statement right above where I specified the parameters. Moving the parameter definition above that statement fixed the problem. Simple solution but very annoying if you don't know what's the problem...

Comment: Ah yes, param blocks have to be first :)